Unity Universal Window Platform get Windows App Certification Kit failed in Supported API test
I want to build a unity game in Universal Window Platform publish in Window Store. But, I got a Windows App Certification Kit failed in Supported API test.
Here is my software used in this build

unity v6000.0.8
visual studio 2019

Here is the result Windows App Certification Kit failed
Supported APIs
Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:
API PrivilegeCheck in api-ms-win-security-base-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. D3D12Core.dll calls this API.
API QuirkIsEnabled in api-ms-win-core-quirks-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. D3D12Core.dll calls this API.
API IsApiSetImplemented in api-ms-win-core-apiquery-l2-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. D3D12Core.dll calls this API.
API GetFileVersionInfoSizeW in api-ms-win-core-version-l1-1-1.dll is not supported for this application type. D3D12Core.dll calls this API.
API UnregisterClassA in user32.dll is not supported for this application type. D3D12Core.dll calls this API.
Impact if not fixed: Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Microsoft Store apps violates the Microsoft Store certification requirements.
How to fix: Review the error messages to identify the API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Microsoft Store apps. If the DLL listed is an allowable redistributable from a NuGET package, SDK or other toolkit, did you forget to add the DLL to your app? Please note, apps that are built in a debug configuration or without .NET Native enabled (where applicable) can fail this test as these environments may pull in unsupported APIs. Retest your app in a release configuration, and with .NET Native enabled if applicable. See the link below for more information:

Before I got this failed test, I have try

try it with Master configuration in visual studio
with visual studio 2022 but it got failed test also.


D3D12Core.dll is a Windows System DLL; does it need to be in your package? (I don't know anything about Unity).
